# What is inside this heater flow switch?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Here is the mystery. In the following youtube video you can see the pin of the flow switch diaphragm extended when the faucet is flowing (the valve is after the flow or pressure switch).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snbKpBdKf8M&feature=youtu.be

Supposedly in a normal pressure switch. As someone described. The pressure will be a maximum when there's no flow, precisely because at zero flow there is no pressure drop anywhere in the system, so the pressure here will be full mains pressure. When the shower-head is on and there's flow, the pressure here will drop.

But in this flow switch diaphragm. It's the opposite. What is in the design in the diaphragm such that when there is no flow (pressure maximum), pressure won't push the pin. The pin will only extend when there is flow.

Some kind of Bernoulli principle, etc. how?

previous posts:

Here is a video of the flow switch turning on right at start of video, I used the control valve before the inlet. However. Note in a multipoint tankless heater, you put the valves (such as sinks, showers) after the heater. I only used it at inlet for testing. So the unit has the water inside always at pressure (when not in used). But here is the thing. When the valves are after the unit or outlet and not in used. The switches are not pushed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q47ZCrGtGJQ&feature=youtu.be

Ok i fried open the flow switch or pressure switch.

[image]

[image]

The tension of the spring is high such that you need high water pressure to push it to turn on the switchrs. It is in inlet side. I think it is a combination flow switch/pressure switch? Because if the water is not used, the switches are off and it's not being pushed. Both for the case where the valve is before the inlet or after the outlet. It's a multipoint tankless water heater.

The reason Panasonic created very high tension spring is so you can't lower the heater power or make it variable. It's either in low (2.5kw),  medium (3.5kw) or High (6kw).

Anyway. I disassembled everything and it's all very simple circuit. The only electronics part is the LED lights.  I can disable the 3.5kw or 6kw by simply removing the switches and the connections to the heating element. What will be left is the 2.5kw heating element.

I just want to know how many variables control a spring. If I will replace the spring, it has to push at 1/3 the strenght and I have to be sure the spring is as good that can bounce back. If it fails, the thermostat cut-out thermal switches will open. Its just theoretical because i plan to buy a new tankless heater where the water temperature can be monitored and heating element adjusted in micro steps.

Original message.

Any illustration what is inside the flow switch water pusher (the white round thing encircled in green label) of this instant tankless multipoint water heater? When there is fast water flow, it pushes the switch on the left of the round white part (shown in red arrow)

[image]

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/521248/152903

Comment: I wrote that but someone told me to ask the detail of the flow switch schematic in the mechanical engineering section.

Comment: The anywer tells you it contains a diaphragm etc.

Answer (score 2):

That is a pressure-sensitive switch. When there is water pressure in the system, it allows the heater circuit to be turned on. When there is no water pressure in the system, it prevents the heaters from being turned on. This prevents the heater from burning up, which it would if the heaters were on and there was no water flow in the system.

Comment: But even with water flow like from washing hands. It doesnt turn on but only turn on if water flow is very strong. Any ideas whether it needs certain pressure or psi to turn on?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/521282/73158 it is a pressure switch.

The resistance of the hose and shower head will cause the pressure to rise with increasing flow.
As you have stated, "When there is fast water flow, it pushes the switch on the left of the round white part".

> Any ideas whether it needs certain pressure or psi to turn on?

Yes. It has to overcome a specified spring pressure.

Comment: I don't think that's right.  The pressure at this point will be a maxuimum when there's no flow, precisely because at zero flow there is no pressure drop anywhere in the system, so the pressure here will be full mains pressure.  When the shower-head is on and there's flow, the pressure here will drop.

Comment: The OP hasn't indicated where the water valve is. I'd expect it to be on the inlet to the system so that pressure is zero when the valve is turned off.

Comment: I fried open the flow switch. See added pictures above and added the details "I think it is a combination flow switch/pressure switch? Because if the water is not used, the switches are off and it's not being pushed. Both for the case where the valve is before the inlet or after the outlet." What you think guys? What is it?

Comment: There is no flow or motion sensor in the switch. There is clearly a pressure diaphragm working against a spring. It's a pressure switch. It is not a flow switch. If the valve is after the switch then the switch would be always on.

Comment: No. If the control valve is after the switch or flow switch or unit, it is not always on. In fact it is off (no pushing done even under constant water pressure). I added a youtube video before I disassembled it. And described I used the control valve before the inlet. However. Note in a multipoint tankless heater, you put the valves (such as sinks, showers) after the heater. I only used it at inlet for testing. So the unit has the water inside always at pressure (when not in used). But here is the thing. When the valves are after the unit or outlet and not in used. The switches are not pushed.

Comment: Here is the clue to add to my comment above. Water flows from center hole to the one shown in the arrow here https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/5629/2eKE4G.jpg it is only pushed when there is flow. So maybe its called a hybrid flow pressure switch? Because without flowing, its not pushed. I assembled the white thing now and connected it to the faucet hose and it pushes when water turned on. When i pressed or blocked the outlet of the white thing, it no longer pushes the pin. So agree its a hybrid flow sensitive pressure switch? Is there such a thing?

Comment: This heater doesn't work with a valve upstream of the heater. The flow control is just the tap (or other outlet) which is downstream.  When the tap is closed, the whole system is pressurised to mains pressure.  When the tap opens, the pressure in the pipework at the heater drops. I don't believe this switch contains any flow sensing - it's just pressure. Whether it's in the heater to cut the heater current when there's no pressure in the system, or to energise the heater when the pressure drops below a threshold (i.e. when the outlet opens) I can't tell from the information available.

Comment: This is schematic of the wiring. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/5091/tOsr0E.jpg the flow switch is normally open. So when there is water flow. It pushes on the switch as you can see in the youtube video and turn on the heater. So the white device is not really a pressure switch. But a flow switch. In multipoint tankless water heater. All controls are after the heater or downstream. But you can also do it at inlet. Because the white device is a flow sensitive device. Not a pressure switch. It looks like a pressure switch buts just a clever flow switch. Agree now?

Comment: To add to above comment. No multipoint tankless water heater manufacturers will use a pressure switch. This is because imagine the water company suddenly turn off the main supply during some maintenance work. Then it will turn on all multipoint water heaters in the houses. Panasonic designs the white device such that only when water flow is strong will it pushes on the power switches by the pin touching it. Has no one else make such a design? It is to make up for their simple power settings. If it gets activated at low flow. It can get too hot. So they need to turn it on only at strong flow.

Comment: I think the white device is powered by flow velocity pressure, not by static pressure. In ordinary pressure switch, static pressure extends the pin. But in this device, static pressure doesn't extend the pin, only by flow velocity. Does it make sense now? Is there other device where it is powered by flow velocity pressure and not by static pressure? don't miss the other 2 comments right above for other desciptions.

Comment: please see update in main with the video of the pin extended only if there is flow, and no extension when no flow and at maximum pressure,... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snbKpBdKf8M&feature=youtu.be  achrn or Transistor, hope you can give an Answer and explain the mysterious phenomenon, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to reply to your comment on niels' post, but I would guess that another reason the heater only runs if the water flowrate is high enough is to avoid overheating the water. You definitely don't want to be boiling the water in the heater, and you don't want to scald someone washing their hands.

Comment: Problem is the shower flow rate is small so using shower cant turn on the heater. The water flow has to be strong so the pin to push to turn on the switch. I wonder if there is a splinklee shower head that can send maximum flow of water so i can use the heater?